# Clean In-App Purchases on Simulator after reinstall

Tags: swift, xcode

After using iOS 16 and Xcode 14, I noticed the subscriptions don't reset after deleting the app.

I'm using StoreKit, if on the simulator I subscribe to a product successfully and delete the app, then reinstall it, the in-app purchase is still active... How can I clear that?

I was looking at some of the [docs](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d) but can't find anything. I'm not using a sandbox user, just triggering the purchase using Xcode Scheme, StoreKit Configuration.

How can the subscriptions be reseted on the simulator?